# Ubuntu 18.04 can not detect headset input device

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone

When my bluetooth headset(JBL tune660nc) is connected to my ubuntu 18.04, it shows as output device, but not as the input device. As a result internal microphone is used(which itself does not work, this is why I need the headset microphone to work) But when the headset is connected to mobile or windows, microphone works properly. How do I solve this? It can be connected with wire, but still having same problem, microphone now detected.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It should show the mic as input if they are connected in HFP/HSP mode as mic input can't be used with A2DP

Comment: @Jeremy31 I have no knowledge about them, so I need to study them now. thanks for the lead. How can I verify that if this is the case?

Comment: You might want to upgrade to 20.04 or 22.04 as 18.04 goes EOL in a few months.  I think you can change it from A2DP to HSP in sound settings on newer Ubuntu versions